# How to use an attribute selector with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I would like to apply a `computed` style to an input form. The [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) explains how to do that, but only for simple styles.

I need to apply the equivalent of

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
  background-color : red; 
}
```

but **it is not clear for me how to convey the `[type="text"]` bit**.

Using it verbatim does not work:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    password: '',
  },
  computed: {
    passwordStyle: function() {
      var style = {}
      style['input[type="text"]'] = 'red';
      style['textarea'] = 'blue';
      return style;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root>">
  <input type="text" name="password" autofocus="true" v-bind:style='passwordStyle'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only pass the style, not the css selector, like:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    password: '',
  },
  computed: {
    passwordStyle: function() {
      return {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      };
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <input type="text" name="password" autofocus="true" :style="passwordStyle">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was so focused on my code that I did not realise that in the example I forgot to pass `background-color` at all...

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain your use-case little bit elaborately, use of `v-bind:style` is when you want to dynamically change the style of some element, depending on some variable, as it is in docs, following code with change the CSS depending on `isActive` and `hasError` variable:

```
<div class="static"
     v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }">
</div>

data: {
  isActive: true,
  hasError: false
}
```

I don't see in your code you are changing style based on any variable.

Comment: This is true, my example was to a minimal one to just have the styles applied. In reality `passwordStyle` will be computed based on a complex set of rules, using other elements of the `vm` `data` variables.

Comment: @WoJ Can you add that use case in little more detail.